# Xamarin ListView not displaying any data

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin

I have a problem where I'm trying to display data inside a `ListView` in my app when binding a list of data to my ListView in XAML. The ListView does not populate with any data at all.

Here is all my coding:

My ***Code-behind***

```
public ObservableCollection<RandomList> randomList = new ObservableCollection<RandomList>();

public App()
{
    MainPage = new MainUI();

    randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Susan", Surname = "Potgieter", School = "Oosterlig" });
    randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Jonathan", Surname = "Visagie", School = "Elspark" });
    randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Gerhard", Surname = "Vermaak", School = "E.G. Jansen" });
    randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Kobus", Surname = "Jacobs", School = "Oosterlig" });          
}
```

My ***XAML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RandomTest.MainUI">
  <StackLayout Padding="0,40,0,0">
    <Label Text="Hello" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Button x:Name="btnGetStudents" Text="Get Students"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lwStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding randomList}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Surname}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When I insert a breakpoint in my code behind where I add the dummy data to the list, I can then see in my XAML here: `<ListView x:Name="lwStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding randomList}">` that there are 4 items in my `randomList`.

The problem is that there is no data in the two bindings below:

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Surname}"/>
```

Can someone please tell or show me what I'm doing wrong in my binding? Or if you need ANY more info or code, please ask! I will be happy to give more info. :)

**EDIT**

I've updated my `RandomList` class and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I still can't get my data to load in my ListView through XAML bindings.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace RandomTest
{
    public class RandomList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                    _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        string _surname;
        public string Surname
        {
            get { return _surname; }
            set
            {
                if (_surname != value)
                    _surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }

        string _school;
        public string School
        {
            get { return _school; }
            set
            {
                if (_school != value)
                    _school = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("School");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how my MainUI.xaml.cs page looks like at the moment:

```
public partial class MainUI : ContentPage
{
    public MainUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainUIModel();

        MainUIModel mainUIModel = (MainUIModel)this.BindingContext;
        mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Susan", Surname = "Potgieter", School = "Oosterlig" });
        mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Jonathan", Surname = "Visagie", School = "Elspark" });
        mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Gerhard", Surname = "Vermaak", School = "E.G. Jansen" });
        mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Kobus", Surname = "Jacobs", School = "Oosterlig" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` inherited in your model which you might have set as `BindingContext`?

Comment: Hello! :) No I have no `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the class. Do you think it could help? It's strange because I can set the itemsource of the listview in code and it displays all the data, but it doesn't work in XAML... :|

Comment: Yes that's required in your model.@CareTaker22 https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Comment: I will go and test `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the class and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I've update my class and my question with the class that i've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it still doesn't return any data. Could the binding in XAML be wrong?

Comment: This doesn't need to be set on the List. It will be added in the page model. If you understand BindingContext.

Comment: Added my ans below.@CareTaker22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model MainUIModel

```
public class MainUIModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<RandomList> _randomList;
    public ObservableCollection<RandomList> randomList
    {
        get { return _randomList; }
        set
        {
            if (_randomList != value)
                _randomList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("randomList");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then in your MainUI Page set the binding context just after initialize component.

```
BindingContext = new MainUIModel();
```

The binding randomList in your Xaml will refer to this new created model, and your Name, Surname will refer to the list model. Both binding context are different. You can add your data by using the below code.

```
MainUIModel mainUIModel = (MainUIModel)this.BindingContext;
mainUIModel.randomList=new ObservableCollection<RandomList>();
    mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Susan", Surname = "Potgieter", School = "Oosterlig" });
    mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Jonathan", Surname = "Visagie", School = "Elspark" });
    mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Gerhard", Surname = "Vermaak", School = "E.G. Jansen" });
    mainUIModel.randomList.Add(new RandomList { Name = "Kobus", Surname = "Jacobs", School = "Oosterlig" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Akash. I've done like you've suggested but i'm getting the error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at the line: `MainUIModel mainUIModel = (MainUIModel)this.BindingContext;`.

Comment: Where have you put this line? It must be in your MainUI page becuase the bindingcontext will set on the MainUI page and `this` also refers to your MainUI page.

Comment: In my `public class App : Application` window, where I add the dummy-data to the list.

Comment: No it will not work, `this` will refer to your App class.

Comment: I've added the line to the `MainUI` page, but it's still giving me the same error. I've also added the list coding where I add data to my `randomList` to the MainUI page. I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong here 0_o, but i've updated my question so you might have a better idea of what i'm doing wrong. Sorry for all the inconvenience!

Comment: Did you try cleaning the solution and building it again?

Comment: Yes sir I have and still no luck.

Comment: Got it, it is with your randomList list, you are adding items without initializing it.`mainUIModel.randomList=new ObservableCollection<RandomList>();` and then add the items. @CareTaker22

Comment: I've got some good and bad news! The good - You were right, I was adding items without initializing it first and now the error is gone. The bad - My ListView still does not display any data when I run it in a simulator. Don't you think it might be something with the XAML binding? Because the c# part (I think is fine).

Comment: Sorry I didn't add OnPropertyChanged("randomList"); maybe because of this.

Comment: Where should I add this? :)

Comment: Amazing! It worked! I can now view everything. I almost can't believe that we have to add so much, just to display data in a list. But nevertheless thank you Akash for all your time and effort!!! :D

Comment: Im glad it helped.

Comment: Oh, and you might just want to remove `public ObservableCollection<RandomList> randomList{ get; set; }` from your solution above. It's extra.

Answer (score 3):

Really all you needed to do was make sure the `ObservableCollection` had a `public getter`. Then you could just set `BindingContext = this` and you could access this on the UI. But as always, there are many many ways to skin these kittens.