# Xamarin.Forms Binding works, but text is not showing

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have tried to bind a list of objects to a `listview` for a long time, but although it works as expected with lists where I don't need to write an itemtemplate (`ObservableCollection<string>` for example), it does not work with lists where i want an `itembinding` to a field of an object in a list:

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
ExampleList = new ObservableCollection<ExampleItem>()
{
    new ExampleItem() {Showing = "Item 1"},
    new ExampleItem() {Showing = "Item 2"}
};
ListView.ItemsSource = ExampleList;
```

**Mainpage.xaml:**

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Showing}" TextColor="White"></TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Although the list items are there(!), the text in the rows just doesn't show up:
[Binding Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0RDu.jpg)

I already tried this solution, result was the same : [Xamarin ListView not displaying any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697579/xamarin-listview-not-displaying-any-data)

ANSWER: 
It seems that binding doesn't (fully) work with fields, the variables need to be **properties**!

Comment: Are you setting the itemsouce for the list after your 'InitializeComponent()' call in the xaml.cs constructor? I believe 'InitializeComponent()' will make the call to update the binding and if your source is set after that call that would explain this behavior.

Comment: I cannot set the Itemssource before 'Initializecomponent()', because the component Listview does not exist beforehand.

Comment: I have the same problem even though I am setting the ItemsSource in XAML, and as @VisualManuel says the items are appearing in the listview but the content is empty.

Comment: @VisualManuel You should have typed the answer and marked it as answer. You really saved lot of my item. My models were written 4 years back checked today just to find those were just variables in class not properties. Because of you I could find this. Really a strange scenario to confuse any developer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the **items** in the ItemsSource implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the setter of each property you are binding to triggers the PropertyChanged event.

That's besides triggering PropertyChanged on the property setter of the ItmsSource.

Comment: Well I tried it, it worked. Then I got curious and removed the INotifypropertyChanged, still worked.
It seems to me that binding doesn't work with fields, it **needs properties**!

Comment: @VisualManuel You have saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ItemsSource to bind the ObservableCollection to the ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextCell Text="{Binding Showing}" TextColor="White" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Also remember that when working with Xamarin.Forms it's better to follow the MVVM pattern. You should have the ObservableCollection in a ViewModel class, and set it as the BindingContext on the View

Edit: The ObservableCollection seems to call OnPropertyChange to update the UI on the Add method. Just add the items to the collection after setting the ItemsSource. That should do the trick

```
ExampleList = new ObservableCollection<ExampleItem>();
ListView.ItemsSource = ExampleList;

ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem() {Showing = "Item 1"});
ExampleList.Add(new ExampleItem() {Showing = "Item 2"});
```

Comment: If I set the ItemsSource in xaml, it just does not display anything.
In my code the items are there, just the text is not showing.
For your second point, I just need this to be the simplest possible example for binding for my bachelor thesis. (:

Comment: @VisualManuel see the update on the answer. Using a ViewModel wouldn't make your binding example more cleaner without sacrificing simplicity

Comment: Same result I am afraid.
 Just because I feel like you got the wrong idea (sorry if that's not the case), the binding of the items works perfectly well, the number of items displayed in the list match the amount I put into it in the background.
 Only the part 'Text="{Binding Showing}" ' is not working. (I am seeing empty list items, as in my uploaded picture).

Comment: @VisualManuel maybe it has to do with the way how you set the background color if you say that the items are actually in the list.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the  comments "Binding doesn't work with fields, it needs properties". I am new to xamarin i struggle with it to. But that's the Clear Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is an old issue and has been well addressed.
But you can also set the ItemSource via XAML.
by doing this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Showing}" TextColor="White"></TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This can help to avoid this kind of issues

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

I hope I was useful somehow